# Is it possible to have a shortcut key to go to previous active tab in iTerm2?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2

I've looked everywhere and don't see any way to quickly go to the previously active tab in iTerm2. Think of <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> in Screen or <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> in tmux.

Looks like it's not possible natively, any way to fix it via some script or patch?

Answer (score -2):

`cmd + 9` would go to the last tab on Mac OSX (Tested on iTerm2 Build 2.1.4)

Comment: that doesn't make sense at all.. after all you access tabs by hitting cmd + <tab number>

Comment: @abbood What do you mean that doesn't make sense at all? It works even with Chrome